# AWS services which provide reverse proxy functionality

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I would like to explore what approaches AWS provide to implement a reverse proxy pattern using native AWS services. I can think of the following services that may or may not be appropriate depending on exactly what functionality is required: Application Load Balancer, API Gateway, CloudFront and AWS Amplify. Can anyone point me to any documentation that would help me understand the suitability of these services or indeed know of any other AWS services that I have not considered? Does anyone have any knowledge or recommendation that they are willing to share?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Keep in mind AWS Amplify itself is not a service, it is more like a developer tool kit